# CDO.Message - Hide password in ASP code?

Tags: email, asp-classic, email-validation, email-spam, cdo.message

Our mail server has been compromised and I think it has to do with a classic ASP page that uses CDO.Message and has the password in plain text.

Is there a way to mask or get around having the password so easily visible?

Comment: Classic ASP it is server side code - you shouldn't be able to see it without FTP or RDP access to your server

Comment: Oh yeah, I would not have caught that, but I completely understand. Thank you.